# Replace blanks with certain characters Using replaceAll() on javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var headers =['Test Text','Test Text Test'];
    for (var i= 0; i<headers.length;i++){
        headers[i] = headers[i].replace(' ', '-');
        console.log('header@@@@@@'+headers[i]);
    }
```

this returns 'Test-Text', 'Test-Text Test'.

In order to get all hyphenated characters, I try using replaceAll() to get a result like 'Test-Text', 'Test-Text-Test'. However, it seems like making an unknown error.

Is there any alternative way to get a proper result I want?

Comment: Refer https://appendto.com/2016/02/replace-spaces-underscores-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some regex as `.replace(/\s+/g, '-')`

Here `g` flag is to replace all.

Reference to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983648/replace-spaces-with-dashes-and-make-all-letters-lower-case)

Comment: is that replaceAll() is deprecated on salesforce javascript? by the way, I used regex suggested, it doesn't work on Salesforce environment.

Comment: Don't think there is a replaceAll function in JavaScript in general,  also regex is faster.

Comment: Thanks Raul, It turns the red character in my IDE on regex, so I thought it's an error...

Comment: Hi Raul, Could you give me an example of regex for replacing two quotes positioned in first and last with blanks?

Comment: replace(/["]+/g, '') this is not accepted on salesforce...